# 5x5 stronglift to lose belly fat/base for future physique/bodybuilding comp

Tags: bodybuilding

Me I'm overweight but not a beginner (slight knee injury though, partial lcl tear but I'll deal with that with physio).

I'm 6'1 and wake up and where between 242-247. I have muscle but only got back in gym last 10 weeks trying different routines (after 1-2 years off) I just did 1 day of the 5x5 and would like to burn the stubborn fat with squats but future goal to possibly do a physique/bodybuilding show for natural. Would this be a good program to do for 3-4 months to build a good frame and muscle before the isolated/bodybuilding exercises later?

Check my IG: @markpolan if you guys want a better look at my physique so you can see what I'm talking about.

Thanks guys!! I was 273 and down in the 240's in 10 weeks. So I wanna keep it going but enjoy lifting big as well. I enjoy compound exercises and get bored with isolation.

[image]

Comment: I am flexing on right, sorry didn't have another picture but just wanted to show that I have some muscles but wanna get bigger and more cut. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I enjoy compound exercises and get bored with isolation.

I think you may be under the impression that bodybuilding training is all about isolation movements.  It is not. Bodybuilding training is about learning what you need to work on to sculpt the best physique you can.  In a sense, you’d be an artist constantly critiquing your physique.  If you need more mass on your deltoids, you perform heavy lifts for deltoids.  Same for any other body part.

Isolation movements typically come into play when preparing for competition.  They are yet another “sculpting” tool that can be utilized to add a “finishing” touch to your physique.

There’s no one “best” program to lose weight.  That’s because you can’t pick and choose where it happens.  If you want to pursue a specific training methodology, go ahead.  But, if your eventual goal is to stand on stage, there’s no reason why you can’t adopt a bodybuilding lifestyle now.  That would mean working on improving your weaknesses and watching your diet.

Lastly, in the early days of bodybuilding, there were no training methodologies.  Guys just went to the gym and lift heavy and ate right.  Guys like Arnold, Frank Zane, and Dennis Tinnerino were able to build phenomenal physiques by constantly adjusting their training to improve their weaknesses while following a sound nutrition plan.

Comment: Very well said. I couldn't agree more. Sometimes when I say things they come out the wrong way. I guess i need to be around 10-13% body fat before I can judge what muscles need more attention then others.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Stronglifts or Starting Strength are very good programs.  You can stay with either of these programs for a couple years or more.

Get your lean body mass where you want it, sculpt through some isolation exercises, and then cut to single digit body fat.

Of course there is some minutia in between all that, but it won't matter until you have a solid base of muscle mass.

Answer (score 0):

Must say your 10 week transformation so far is already nothing short of being amazing!

Both SS and SL are good programs and you should continue till you reach at least 1-2x your bodyweight in large lifts like deadlift and back squat. Just like you I do not like isolation exercises, I feel it does not challenge me enough. Also the focus is not there. With barbell complexes its much better and it definitely helps in building good strength which will be the base for you when you want to branch out to bodybuilding.

P.S: My IG is @pravfit and the goal is to double the strength this year.